# selects only return partial result

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, node-mysql

I have around 24k of rows in mysql database. Now using nodejs I would like to query and then store it in json file.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : '10.1.1.2',
    user : 'xxx',
    password : 'xxx',
    database : 'xxx'

});

connection.connect();
var json = '';
var query = 'SELECT * FROM st_training  GROUP BY EndDate ORDER BY StartDate DESC';
var query2 =  'SELECT * FROM st_training WHERE EmployeeID=901 GROUP BY EndDate ORDER BY StartDate DESC'; 
connection.query(query, function(err, results) {
if (err)  { throw err;
}

else {
jsonV = JSON.stringify(results);
console.log(jsonV);

 fs.writeFile('table.json', JSON.stringify(results), function (err) {

  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
 }
 connection.end();

  });
```

I can verify only partial around 600 rows being saved from console.log(jsonV) output or in table.json file. 
What could go wrong here? is it there is a max limitation for JSON.stringify ?

Comment: isn't your WHERE CLAUSE filtering the result

Comment: yes, where will filter the result , but  I would need something different by query all rows for the purpose of migrating the data into mongodb....

Comment: remove WHERE CLAUSE I guess

Comment: You are looking at query2..the one got problem is query....

Comment: try this in query SELECT * FROM st_training   ORDER BY StartDate DESC

Comment: try `console.log(results.length)`, you can check how many rows are retrived there.. if you get 600 then there is something wrong in your query.

Comment: Right...it looks like node-mysql cant execute group by sql statement

Comment: Before jumping to any conclusion, show us results of this query: `SELECT count(*) as a,count(EndDate) as b,count(distinct EndDate) as c FROM st_training` (you can run it directly using command line mysql client or phpmyadmin or anything)

Comment: Here you go ..a =  23849, b = 23849 , c =605